# Put Application in Main System Tray

Tags: c#, vb.net, system, tray

Using NotifyIcon, the application by only appears when you click "Show hidden icons" in Windows
[image]

I want my application to always be shown in the system tray, like this
[image]

Can this be done in VB.NET/C#?

Comment: Nope. It's the user and the OS who pick which icons are shown and which are hidden. You have no control over this

Comment: Just to add on to what @KevinGosse said, I think it was starting with Windows Vista when that change was made. You can no longer decide where your system tray icon will be shown since then.